# Need help with creating a simple obfuscator using Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, assemblies, obfuscation, mono.cecil

Like the title says I need help using Mono.Cecil... I want to use it to make a simple Obfuscator (even though I know they're not simple lmfao, but I'm pretty sure that I can do it)

I have no experience in obfuscation, so basically can someone just give me a simple example of how to use Mono.Cecil to encrypt variables and sign assemblies?

This is what I've done so far:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using Mono.Cecil;

    namespace AppSigner
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Signing DummyApp.exe");
                AssemblyDefinition sourceAssembly = AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly("DummyApp.exe");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are going to have to try harder than that. We all had to.

Comment: how? i dont know anything else. i have been sitting here just looking at all the different class names for like 2 hours and have no idea what does what. considering the fact that the developer made no documentation of Mono.Cecil makes it even harder. i cant get even a small example...

Comment: Try CCI if you don't like Mono.Cecil.

Comment: @Matt: I suggest you read ECMA-335 then. It is the exact document for Mono.Cecil.

Comment: Also, if you are a beginner programmer, this will be very hard to understand. If you are ambitious though, go for it. The information will be very valuable in any future .NET endeavours.

Comment: im not new to .NET just C# i have been using VB for about 3 years now and even though im still not that good i know my way around xP thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @Matt, why don't you use Mono.Cecil or CCI with VB.NET?

Comment: @SK-logic they make Mono for VB :O

Comment: @Matt, you can use any .net library with VB.NET

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links for you to get started:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513319/mono-cecil-documentation-and-tutorials/1610581#1610581
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MonoCecilChapter1.aspx

Please check the above out... then create some code and come back with specific code snippets and questions!

Comment: thanks, the code project link is one thing that i was looking for and will definitely help me with signing assemblies :D

Comment: please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at this [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MonoCecilChapter1.aspx) and this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513319/mono-cecil-documentation-and-tutorials) question and these questions on [Stackoverflow on Mono.Cecil](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mono.cecil/hot)

Comment: yes i have, viewed them both. xP